# Strange message about template changes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template that when double-clicked runs an AutoOpen macro to prompt the user for some info to be placed in the resulting document. If I double-click the template's file name and open it, but then close the user dialog that the AutoOpen brings up, make no changes of any sort, and close the resulting document, I get a message from Word saying that I "have modified styles, building blocks (such as cover pages or headers), or other content that is stored in " and asks if I want to save changes to the template. Actually, it asks this twice in a row.

This seems most strange, at least to me. Any ideas as to what's going on, or where I should start looking (presumably in the code other than the AutoOpen)?

Thank you!

Haven't tried anything yet...not sure where in code to look for what's going on.

Comment: Try holding down the left shift key as you open your file (keep the key depressed until the file is fully open). That will open the file without running your AutoOpen code. 
Then look for Auto macros. You should also check out your "Normal.dot" file to see if there are Auto macros in there that are being triggered.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/auto-macros

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/template-question/1c4d61fd-e848-4ad6-83de-e024f1841bfd and answered there.